# Web scraping words and phrases from word hippo

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a bit of code that I use to extract a list of words from word hippo based on the length of the word in this case 10. In this case I am trying to get all the synonyms (with a length of 10) for "overview" but find that any synonym with spaces in it doesn't come through, for example "Brain wave" doesn't come through even when I specify a letter length of 10.

This piece of code I have puts a list of the words which do not contain spaces. How do I amend it to get synonyms like "brain wave" which have spaces in them?

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page = requests.get("https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/overview.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

'Change this'
keyword = "overview"

listing = []
length = 10
synonyms = soup.select('.relatedwords')
for i in range(0, 100):
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    csvname = str(keyword) + str(i) + ".xlsx"
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    DataFrame = pd.DataFrame((synonyms[i].text.strip().split()))
    InitList = DataFrame[0].tolist()


    for item in InitList:
        if len(item) == length:
           listing.append(item)
    print (listing)

    DataFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(listing)
    out_path = "FIlePathName" + csvname
    DataFrame1.to_excel(out_path, index = False)
```

'''

I have the correct FilePath.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You're calling `.split()` on the text, so "Brain wave" becomes two separate words.  "Brain" by itself is only five letters, so it doesn't match.

Comment: @JohnGordon How do I resolve the problem though? Should I remover .split() ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to change the following line of code:

```
DataFrame = pd.DataFrame((synonyms[i].text.strip().split()))
```

to this line of code

```
DataFrame = pd.DataFrame((synonyms[i].text.split("\n")))
```